# Optimization of a problem with quadratic objective and quadratic constraints and alternative formulations

Tags: quadratic-programming, non-convex-optimization, second-order-cone-programming

Suppose we have $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$, we want to minimize

\begin{align}
\min&\quad\|Ax\|_2^2 \\
\text{s.t.}&\quad x^\top C_1x = 1, \\
&\quad x^\top C_2 x = 1, \\
&\quad Dx > 0
\end{align}

Is there any optimization method to handle this?

Actually, the first and second constraints aims to force part of $x$ has the norm of $1$. The third constraint aims to force part of $x$ has the positive value.

Ignore the $Dx > 0$ constraint, can we formulate the optimization into a generalized eigenvalue problem or second-order cone programming?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A thought: we can simplify our analysis somewhat using an SVD of $A$. In particular, if $A = U \Sigma V^T$ and we make the substitution $y = V^Tx$, then the problem becomes
\begin{equation}
\min~~~ \|\Sigma y\|_2^2 \\
~s.t.~~~ y^\top (V^\top C_1 V) y = 1, \\
~~~~~~~~~~y^\top (V^TC_2V) y = 1, \\
~~(DV)y > 0.
\end{equation}
With that, our objective function simply becomes 
$$
\|\Sigma y\|_2^2 = \sigma_1^2 y_1^2 + \cdots + \sigma_n^2y_n^2.
$$
We could also make the further substitution $z = \Sigma y$ so that the objective function is just $\|z\|_2^2$.

Comment: Are we given that $C_1,C_2$ are positive definite?

Comment: @ Ben Grossmann, Thanks for the suggestion. $C_1$ and $C_2$ are both positive definite. Actually they are diagonal matrix with the format like this $C_1 = \rm{diag}(1,1,1,0,0,0,\cdots,0)$, $C_2 = \rm{diag}(0,0,0,1,1,1,\cdots,0)$